# How to send a continuous stream through ssh

Tags: ssh, video-streaming, stream

**Given a named pipe, how can I send a continuous stream of this pipe through ssh?**

The `netcat` equivalent of what I am looking for is

- from client

  ```
  dd if=myfifo | nc -l 12345
  ```
- from server

  ```
  nc <client IP> 12345 > stream
  ```

Comment: Can you explain what the two lines are doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat source.data | ssh ${hostname} 'cat > destination.data'
```

Alternatively:

```
ssh ${hostname} 'cat > destination.data' < source.data
```